# Margin of one element affecting the element at its side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple, fluid, responsive two column layout (just for the sake of learning CSS), consisting of a sidebar and a main section.

I was able to create the sidebar with 100% height, position the main content at its side, but when I put a H1 inside my main section... tada! Its margin created a margin for the sidebar as well.

Here's a minimum code that presents the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }

      #sidebar {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        width:25%;
        min-height:100%;
        border-right:1px solid #222;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
      }

      #main {
        margin-left:25%;
        display:block;
      }

      h1 {
        padding:2%;
        /* margin:0; */
        /* defining the margin as zero aligns 
         * everything at the top */
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="sidebar">
      Let's reach for the stars!
    </header>

    <section id="main">
      <h1>Nope!</h1>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox, happened in both.

[I've created this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmkCQ/2/), and thanks to a comment from cimmanon, the behavior is the same.

Well, I'm lost. Am I missing something really simple?

Is this approach a good way to make a two column layout? I inspired myself reading the CSS from the [Svbtle blogs](https://svbtle.com).

Comment: JSFiddle adds a reset improperly labeled as "normalization" by default.  See without the normalization:  http://jsfiddle.net/PmkCQ/2/

Comment: oh, didn't know that. In my example I was relying on the fact that a h1 had a margin, and the jsFiddle with the "normalization" stripped the margin from h1, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, absolute positioning should be avoided unless you really do want the element removed from the document's flow.  If you have a page where `#main` ends up having shorter content than `#sidebar` and the user's display isn't tall enough to display all of `#sidebar`'s contents, you're going to have your content clipped off.

My favored way of achieving equal height columns is to use the `display: table` CSS properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/PmkCQ/3/

```
html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }

body { display: table }

      #sidebar {
        width:25%;
        border-right:1px solid #222;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
      }

      #sidebar, #main {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align: top; /* optional */
      }

      h1 {
        padding:2%;
        margin-top: 0;
        /* margin:0; */
        /* defining the margin as zero aligns 
         * everything at the top */
      }
```

There's other ways, of course, but this one is less brittle than floats or absolute positioning.  The only down side is that IE7 doesn't support these properties, so they'll continue using the element's previously defined (or default) display setting (for `div`, it will be `block`).

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to the h1 and it won't influence the side bar. Then you can set any margin you want.

The reason it seemed fine in JSFiddle is probably the styles applied from their styles (inspect the h1 and you'll see it has `margin:0`).

Comment: thanks, but do you know why it affects it at the first place? it makes no sense to me even with the display:block (or else I have a big misconception about how the displays work in CSS)

Comment: besides that, a better approach would be to put the display:inline-block at the section, not at the h1, right?